# Interpretation of Python Output regarding utf8 characters

Tags: python, ascii, frequency, analysis, python-3.7

I have a .txt file and I need to count the frequency of all characters in it, in order to do a simple frequency analysis for my cryptology excercise.

I think the code worked fine but it appears that Python has trouble to read characters such as Ä,Ö,ß etc. (German alphabet). As the code is reading a .txt file I assume it is in utf8 format.

This is the output:

```
Counter({' ': 168, 'S': 136, '\xc3': 103, 'Z': 83, 'G': 80, 'P': 80,
'W': 76, 'J': 66, 'O': 63, 'Q': 62, 'R': 57, 'U': 57, 'L': 47, '\x84': 43,
'K': 39, '\x9c': 28, 'X': 25, 'A': 23, 'C': 22, '\x9f': 18, 'E': 17, 'N':
17, '\x96': 14, ',': 11, 'D': 8, 'Y': 8, 'T': 6, 'V': 6, 'B': 5, '"': 4,
"'": 3, 'F': 2, 'M': 2, '!': 1, '-': 1, '?': 1}) [Finished in 0.1s]
```

My question is how to interpret the backslash characters such as '\xc3' and so on. I can't find anything online on how to translate it?

Edit (my code):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('/Users/StB/Downloads/text.txt') as f:
    c = Counter()
    for x in f:
        c += Counter(x.strip())
print c
```

Edit 2:

new output:

```
Counter({' ': 168, 'S': 136, 'Z': 83, 'P': 80, 'G': 80, 'W': 76, 'J': 66, 'O': 63, 'Q': 62, 'R': 57, 'U': 57, 'L': 47, 'Ä': 43, 'K': 39, 'Ü': 28, 'X': 25, 'A': 23, 'C': 22, 'ß': 18, 'N': 17, 'E': 17, 'Ö': 14, ',': 11, 'Y': 8, 'D': 8, 'T': 6, 'V': 6, 'B': 5, '"': 4, "'": 3, 'F': 2, 'M': 2, '-': 1, '!': 1, '?': 1})
```

new Code:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('/Users/StB/Downloads/text.txt', encoding= 'utf - 8') as f:
    c = Counter()
    for x in f:
        c += Counter(x.strip())
print (c)
```

endcoding does not work on the version i had running on sublime text. Worked fine in IDLE though!

Comment: Hi @StB, can you please post your code as well?

Comment: First of all, for this question it is critical to know if you're on [tag:python2] or [tag:python3]. I believe the former, but do tag appropriately. You need to understand bytes, strings, encoding, codepoints, string literals, and I might be forgetting something. `\x9c` is a byte that has value of hexadecimal 9C, or decimal 156; it was not analysed as a Unicode character. EDIT: As toti08 says, it is also important for us to see how you read in the file.

Comment: @toti08 edited it in!

Comment: @Amadan actually I am using python3

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried specifying the encoding type? `open('/Users/StB/Downloads/text.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')`

Comment: `print c` is invalid Python 3, you would have gotten an error. It is valid Python 2 though. Are you 100% sure about which interpreter you are using?

Comment: @toti08 that doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Amadan interesting, didn't know that! I was sure I'm on 3.7 but it appears as if i have taken the standard Python version of Sublime Text..

Comment: So I have combined the information both of you have given me and then i ran the script in IDLE, to make sure its python 3.7 im on. See Edit 2 for the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Python 2, you will need to explicitly decode the string you are reading into Unicode. You can also use `Counter.update` method to avoid creating and discarding `Counter` objects.

```
from collections import Counter
with open('/Users/StB/Downloads/text.txt') as f:
    c = Counter()
    for x in f:
        c.update(x.decode('utf-8').strip())
print c
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I need to get Python 3 running on my sublime text. So much confusion caused by that.

Comment: "First of all, for this question it is critical to know if you're on [tag:python2] or [tag:python3].", first thing I said :D No worries, as long as it's solved.